# event listener fires only once

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm learning Switch in JS. I created an array of names and I made a click event to pick a random name but it works only once. Another clicks repeats the same choice again and again. The random() function doesn't seem to work. How to do it in vanilla JS in a simple way? Can anyone explain it to a learner using only basic methods?

```
   <button id="chooseRandom" onclick="checkPerson()">Choose</button>
```

```
  const people = ["Harriet", "Steve", "Ana", "Jessica", "Jacob", "Don"];
let randomPerson = people[Math.floor(Math.random() * people.length)];


let btn = document.querySelector("#chooseRandom")

function checkPerson () {
    switch(randomPerson) {
        case randomPerson = "Ana":
            console.log("Hi, Ana.");
            break;
        case randomPerson = "Jessica":
            console.log("Hi, Jessica.");
            break;
        case randomPerson = "Harriet":
            console.log("Hi, Harriet.");
            break;
        default:
            console.log("I'm not interested in men.");
    } 
  }
```

Comment: You need to pick the random person in the function. You're just doing it once when the page loads.

Comment: We see questions like this multiple times a day, either with a random variable or the value of an input. Why is it so hard for new programmers to understand that the variable doesn't update automatically?

Comment: @Barmar I saw many similar questions asked but they were totally different. They used advanced methods and jQuery. I've been looking for this answer all day. Trust me. I'm just a learner. I was looking in the wrong direction. I thought I had to use other methods but it only needed to move one line into the fuction.

Comment: I'm asking why this question even comes up. Can't you see that you only assign the variable once?

Comment: Now I don't understand. You accepted the answer, which says the same thing I said. Do you understand why the answer works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247928/discussion-between-tomdev-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a new random people every time the checkPerson is called. So, you need calculate it inside of the function.

```
const people = ["Harriet", "Steve", "Ana", "Jessica", "Jacob", "Don"];

let btn = document.querySelector("#chooseRandom")

function checkPerson () {
    const randomPerson = people[Math.floor(Math.random() * people.length)];

    switch(randomPerson) {
        case randomPerson = "Ana":
            console.log("Hi, Ana.");
            break;
        case randomPerson = "Jessica":
            console.log("Hi, Jessica.");
            break;
        case randomPerson = "Harriet":
            console.log("Hi, Harriet.");
            break;
        default:
            console.log("I'm not interested in men.");
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You assign a value to `randomPerson` only once. Move it to `checkPerson ()`

Answer (score -1):

```
const people = ['Harriet','Steve','Ana','Jessica','Jacod','Don' ];

function checkPerson(){
   const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * people.length);
   console.log(`Hi, ${people[num]}.`); 
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem a need to turn the `people` array into an object if you're going to use it as an array-like object. Nevertheless, please explain why this solves the problem of OP.

Comment: Interesting approach, but not exactly what I had in mind. I excluded some elements of the array. But I go my answer already above. Thanks @juazsh